# How to make only 1 screen appear over lock screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using the following code to show an alarm ringing screen over the lock screen:

```xml
<activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:exported="true"
      ...
      android:showWhenLocked="true"
      android:showOnLockScreen="true"
      android:turnScreenOn="true"
      ...
      >
```

Issue is that the rest of the screens in my app now appear over the lock screen too. For example, when app is opened and user locks device, when they turn screen on again, my app appears there instead of the lock screen. Is there any way in flutter to differentiate between which screens appear over the locks screen?